# Android radio button multiple select

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, radio-group

Long story short. I am creating radio buttons inside radio group. I will do filtering for my table depending on what user selects. I have one radio button checked by default. So when I try to check other button it stays checked. In fact both buttons get checked. It is so weird. Maybe that is happens because I do everything programmatically. Desing is still in progress. I just stoped here because I don't know if it is visual bug or not. I am using Kotlin for android developemnt.

Display buttons:

```
    private fun displayChoices(choices: List<FiltersList.Choice>, multipleChoice: Boolean) {
        val radioGroup = RadioGroup(this)
        for (choice in choices) {
            val button = if (multipleChoice) {
                CheckBox(this)
            } else {
                RadioButton(this)
            }

            button.apply {
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
                    setMargins(16, 8, 16, 8)
                }
                text = choice.display
                isChecked = choice.selected
                setTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorTextClicked, null))
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    buttonTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorButton, null))
                }
            }
            radioGroup.addView(button)
        }
        filters_content.addView(radioGroup)
    }
```

My layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorFilterBoxBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FilterDialogActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/filters_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The view:
[image: Problem looks like this]

I select Any Date button programmatically and it is stay selected. I get data from the server which items need to be seleced by default.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the dialog xml?

Comment: I render everything in LinearLayout id: filters_content. All this activity is my dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so at first I thought it was because you were setting other views inside the radioGroup, as radioButtons need to be a direct child. But that wasn't the case here, The issue is when creating the radioButtons inside a radioGroup programmatically you need to assign specific id's to each radioButton.

Didn't find a doc, but I am guessing a radioGroup makes use of the button ids to make the mutually exclusive. So simple solution set an `id` to each radioButton you are creating
As for the id you use this is what the doc mentions.

> The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.

If its in Java you could use `button.setId(choices.indexOf(choice)+1001);`. I'm not so good with Kotlin but i guess the Kotlin equivalent would be

```
id = choices.indexOf(choice) + 1001 //where 1001 i just a random int I used to try avoid conflict
```

Set an id for the buttons and that should solve your issue. Good Luck.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your time.